# Pasar parametros en URL

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Necesito mandar los detalles de un producto a otra pagina que me muestra mas especificaciones, el codigo que tengo es el siguiente:

```
  const setDetails = () => {
    setId(id);
    setTitle(title);
    setImage(image);
    setPrice(price);
    setRating(rating);
  };
  return (
    <div className="product">
      <div className="product__info">
          <div>
            <Link to="./ProductDetail">
              <p onMouseEnter={setDetails}>{title}</p>
            </Link>
          </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Product;
```

Cunado paso el mouse por arriba del titulo, llamo a la funcion que toma los datos, y al hacer clic debo mandarlos, pero la siguiente pagina no recibe nada

el codigo de la pagina que debe recibirlo es el siguiente:

```
function ProductDetail({ id, title, image, price, rating }) {
  const [{ basket, user }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
  return (
    <div className="checkout">
      <div className="checkout__left">
          <CheckoutProduct
              id={id}
              title={title}
              image={image}
              price={price}
              rating={rating}
              hideButton={true}
            />
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ProductDetail;
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes pasar los datos por props en el componente `Link` empleando la propiedad [state](https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/api#link)

Dependiendo de que versión estés utilizando puedes hacer los siguiente:

```
//ReactRouter v5

<Link
  to={{
    pathName: "/ProductDetail",
    state: { id, title, image, price, rating },
  }}
>
  <p onMouseEnter={setDetails}>{title}</p>
</Link>;
```

```
//ReactRouter v6

<Link to="/ProductDetail" state={{id, title, image, price, rating}}>
  <p onMouseEnter={setDetails}>{title}</p>
</Link>
```

y en el componente donde te dirige ese link recibes los datos empleando el hook de React Router [`useLocation()`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-location)

```
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'

function ProductDetail({ id, title, image, price, rating }) {
  const location = useLocation()
  const { id, title, image, price, rating  = location.state
  const [{ basket, user }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
  return (
    <div className="checkout">
      <div className="checkout__left">
          <CheckoutProduct
              id={id}
              title={title}
              image={image}
              price={price}
              rating={rating}
              hideButton={true}
            />
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Estoy utilizando ReactRouter v6, pero no funciona, probe con ambas soluciones (por las dudas) y sigue sin ercibir los datos.

Comment: Debe haber algo en tu implementacion que puede estar afectando el uso de useLocation. Te dejo por aca un Playground en el que utilizo React Router v6 https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xzfdv4?file=src/App.js